# How to create an anonymous type with calculated values

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have this structure:

```
class Ticket
{
 int Id;
 bool Void;
}
```

Is it possible to use LINQ to get an Anonymous Type with this two aggregated properties?

```
select new {totalVoid = numVoidTickets, totalNonVoid = numNonVoidTickets};
```

I thought this could be an approach:

```
from t in Tickets
select new { totalVoid = t.Id.Count(x => x.Void == true, 
totalNonVoid = t.Id.Count(x => x.Void == false };
```

but intellisense is not showing Count() after I type `t.Id` nor `t`.

Comment: `t` represents the Id of single `Ticket` object how come you can expect a `Count` method there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to minimize the number of calls to the database, you can use grouping to perform all of your aggregation in one call. To group the entire collection, just use `GroupBy(t => 1)`.

```
var results = Tickets.GroupBy(t => 1).Select(t => new
{
    totalVoid = t.Count(o => o.Void == true),
    totalNonVoid = t.Count(o => o.Void == false)
});
```

Comment: Grouping by a constant is creative :) But backwards and not required.

Comment: @usr It is if you want to do this as one query instead of two.

Comment: Hm actually that's true. This is the only way I know to make an ORM do this in one query. +1

Answer (score 7):

`t` is single item in your expression.

You don't need outer `Select` / 'from` to get this information:

```
var result = new 
{ 
  totalVoid = Tickets.Count(x => x.Void == true), 
  totalNonVoid = Tickets.Count(x => x.Void == false)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Ticket> tickets = new List<Ticket>()
{
    new Ticket{Id=10,Void =true},
    new Ticket{Id=10,Void =true},
    new Ticket{Id=10,Void =true},
    new Ticket{Id=10,Void =false},
    new Ticket{Id=10,Void =false},
    new Ticket{Id=10,Void =true},
    new Ticket{Id=10,Void =true},
};
var result = tickets.GroupBy(x => x.Void)
    .Select(x=>new 
    {
        typeVoid = x.Key,
        coutVoid = x.Count()
    });
foreach (var x in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("count = {0} type ={1}", x.coutVoid, x.typeVoid);
}
```